# Блокировка navigation drawer

Tags: java, android

Есть фрагмент в котором используется [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer). Хочу сделать так: когда я перехожу на другой фрагмент блокировалось боковое меню

Comment: что именно значит ваше "блокировалось"? Не показывалось? Не нажималось? Не работало?

Comment: Что бы не показывалось в другом фрагменте.

Comment: так не реализовывайте drawer  в другом Активити, он и показываться не будет

Answer (score 1):

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

**upd:** [can-i-lock-the-drawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer#can-i-lock-the-drawer)

Comment: Нету там такого метода. Я использовал библиотеку mikepenz

Comment: @user207012, есть такой метод, обновил ответ.